# Cannot connect to computer over RPC

Tags: windows, rpc

I am trying to execute the command: tasklist /S computer-bureau on an other computer in our network.

I always get the fault: RPC server is unavailable. When I execute the command on the computer self it is working, however when I execute it from another computer in the same domain, I get the RPC server unavailable error.

We have a server with Windows SBS 2011 Essentials and several windows 7 clients in the domain. All the Windows 7 clients are working, except the "computer-bureau", this is not working.

The firewall is off on the computer.

Comment: This one odd computer, is it win7 too? or is it different (vista/xp)? Windows HomeGroup is not compatible to versions previous to win7.

Comment: All the other Windows 7 clients are also member of active directory and are working fine. Except the one computer that doens't work. Weird. When I try to manage the computer from the active directory server, I can't succeed with the fault cannot find the network path to the computer specified. so there is some sort of problem there I think.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing Files Between Windows 7 and XP/Vista:

Make sure both of the machines are on the same Workgroup (default is WORKGROUP/HOMEGROUP depending on OS version).

Win7 - Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center 
select "Change advanced sharing settings." and turn on Network Discovery & File Print Sharing & maybe "turn off password protection".

You should now see your XP/Vista machine in your network.